# Convert a DataTable to a Dictionary<T1,T2> using Generics and extension methods

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I am attempting to create a Dictionary from my DataTable. Currently i do this by first creating a IList and then looping through the List and adding them to a dictionary individually specifying the Primary key property of the resulting object in the list on a case by case basis.

I was wondering if this could be done using generics.

Ive currently got the following code, which doesnt compile or work:

```
public static IDictionary<T1, T2> ToDictionary<T1,T2>(this DataTable table) where T2 : new()
{
    IList<PropertyInfo> properties = GetPropertiesForType<T2>();
    IDictionary<T1,T2> result = new Dictionary<T1,T2>();
    Dictionary<string, int> propDict = GetPropertyDictionary(properties, table);
    T1 PK;
    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
    {
        var item = CreateDictItemFromRow<T2>((DataRow)row, properties, propDict);
        result.Add(item. item); //not sure here
    }
    return result;
}
```

Essentially i would like to call the following:

```
Dictionary<int, MyDBClass> Items = DataTable.ToDictionary<int,MyDBClass>();
```

or

```
Dictionary<Int16,MyDBClass> Items = DataTable.ToDictionary<Int16, MyDBClass>();
```

Im assuming somewhere i need to pass the primary key property name to this function. Failing that i can safely assume the first column in my Datatable contains the primary key (although its not safe to assume it is always an int (it maybe a short or byte)).

I also understand this could quite easily be done using LINQ, but i havent got that far in C# and wish to alter existing application.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a problem with what you asking, how it would be possible if the DataTable has more than two columns???

Comment: MyDBClass is a class with ALL of the column information as properties. I can get it out currently as a List<MYDBClass> however i then manually add these to a dictionary. I would just like to genericize this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
        public static class Extensions
        {
            public static Dictionary<TKey, TRow> TableToDictionary<TKey,TRow>(
                this DataTable table,
                Func<DataRow, TKey> getKey,
                Func<DataRow, TRow> getRow)
            {
                return table
                    .Rows
                    .OfType<DataRow>()
                    .ToDictionary(getKey, getRow);
            }
        }



        public static void SampleUsage()
        {
            DataTable t = new DataTable();

            var dictionary = t.TableToDictionary(
                row => row.Field<int>("ID"),
                row => new {
                    Age = row.Field<int>("Age"),
                    Name = row.Field<string>("Name"),
                    Address = row.Field<string>("Address"),
                });
        }
```

By the way, you need to include the assembly, System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll, to use the Field extension method.

If you have any other questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: +1 Many Thanks! Not exactly what i was after but it helped me find the solution.

Comment: Glad I could help you find the solution. I understand you basically had a 2 in 1 question, so I went for the first answer first. I assume you went one step further by replacing the usage method to be a bit more dynamic using reflection mapping between your target type and querying the schema fro the table?

Comment: Correct. If anyone needs the answer its below. Big thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Ah yes, I only see your completed method now. That's fantastic. I do love my extension methods, because they're so reusable and it makes one's code so much more fluent to read.

Answer (score 2):

With a great help from base2, here was my completed method:

```
public static IDictionary<TKey, T> ToDictionary<TKey, T>(this DataTable table, Func<DataRow,TKey> getKey) where T : new()
{
    IList<PropertyInfo> properties = GetPropertiesForType<T>();
    IDictionary<TKey, T> result = new Dictionary<TKey, T>();
    Dictionary<string, int> propDict = GetPropertyDictionary(properties, table);
    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
    {
        var item = CreateItemFromRow<T>((DataRow)row, properties, propDict);
        TKey pk = getKey((DataRow)row);
        result.Add(pk,item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

which can be called like so:

```
IDictionary<Int16,DBClient> Clients = sql.GetDataTable("SELECT * FROM Clients").ToDictionary<Int16,DBClient>(r => r.Field<Int16>("PrimaryKeyField"));
```

Comment: If anyone needs the called private methods (GetPropertiesForType(), GetPropertyDictionary() and CreateItemFromRow()) please ask in a comment.

Comment: If you feel really adventurous, you could generate an expression tree to do this for you, then compile a Func<Row,T> delegate for the CreateItemFromRow. This way you you would only need to use reflection once per target type.

Comment: Interesting, but i honestly have no idea on Expression Trees. I guess the propDict (which is used as a mapping lookup for the reflected properties) doesnt do this? I guess ill be reading up some more :)

Comment: You'll enjoy expression trees once you get the hang of it. Very powerful stuff.

Comment: I found this article which you might find useful, complete with a performance analysis. http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/02/03/performance-using-dynamic-code-to-copy-property-values-of-two-objects.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Petapoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) It allows you to retrieve from the database into CLR objects and Lists. It doesn't have much overhead.

Comment: +1 Yes this looks like exactly what i require, however for interests sake I would like to know how to acheive this> I will probably adopt this for future projects

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve through reflection check out this [link](http://oops-solution.blogspot.in/2012/01/convert-dataset-into-list-using.html) may help you
In this post i have tried to convert a dataset into list